# HTML5 : How can I add a wrapping div to drag & drop text

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I am dragging text from a paragraph with text / html to a contenteditable div.
I would like to add a wrapping div to the dropped selected text.
I have tried manipulating all the drag and drop listeners with no success.
I thought of manipulating via dataTransfer - but it seems to fail.

```
e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', '<div>' + e.dataTransfer.getData('Text') +'</div>');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the drag/drop code for chrome recently (v24). It appears you need to specify the `dragover` handler for the drop target and call `event.preventDefault();` action on it, otherwise the drop wont work.

If your problem is only the wrapping of the dragged content, you have a nice example here [html5rock presentation](http://slides.html5rocks.com/#drag-and-drop)

As the previous answer states, you can get the dropped content on the `drop` handler. Although in chrome I use

```
 var text = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
 var html = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
```

You can get all available mime types by examining the `e.dataTransfer.types`

It seems that you can set the dragged content on `dragstart`, but not read it, so this is only available on `drop` event listener.

```
 event.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain')
```

Comment: Works! Thanks!  
Now I have another issue: I add a    ` "<cite>" + e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html') + "</cite>" `      
and now all the other content in the contenteditable div that I add after dragging gets <cite></cite>

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Can you exmplain in your main question maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I have following code working in Firefox 16.

```
<style>
    #drophere {
        box-shadow: 0 0 3px #aaa;
        height: 200px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 300px;
    }
</style>

<p id="dragthis" draggable="true">Lorem possum Lorem possum Lorem possum Lorem possum Lorem possum Lorem possum Lorem possum Lorem possum Lorem possum Lorem possum Lorem possum Lorem possum Lorem possum Lorem possum Lorem possum Lorem possum </p>

<div id="drophere" contenteditable droppable="true"></div>

<script>
    var p = document.getElementById('dragthis');

    p.addEventListener( 'dragstart',
                        function(event) {
                            event.dataTransfer.setData('Text', event.target.innerHTML)
                        },
                        true
                    );

    var drop = document.getElementById('drophere');

    drop.addEventListener( 'drop',
                           function( event ) {
                               event.target.innerHTML = "&lt;div&gt;" + event.dataTransfer.getData('Text') + "&lt;/div&gt;";
                               event.preventDefault();
                           },
                           true
                       );
</script>
```